# Angular. Custom directive with ng-repeat inside

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, html5-canvas

I have a custom directive with ng-repeat inside.
Ng-repeat's template looks like

```
<div ng-repeat='(key, item) in items'>
    <canvas id='canvas-{{ key }}'></canvas>
</div>
```

After creating all items using ng-repeat I need to fill each canvas with different line.
I've tried to do it within link function of my directive:

```
link: function(scope, element) {
    scope.items = /* some data */
    $.each(items, function(key, item) {
        // some logic here with canvas like
        var drawingCanvas = document.getElementById('canvas-' + key);
        var context = drawingCanvas.getContext("2d");
        context.beginPath();
        context.moveTo(0, 0);
        context.lineTo(200, 100);
    });
}
```

But the way I wrote above doesn't work because when I call $.each, ng-repeat haven't rendered corresponding layout.
How should I rewrite my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `$timeout`, this will do the trick. `$timeout` will force a `$digest` cicle which will trigger the `ngRepeat` directive forcing it to render the results.

```
$timeout(function(){
    scope.items = /* some data */
    $.each(items, function(key, item) {
        // some logic here with canvas like
        var drawingCanvas = document.getElementById('canvas-' + key);
        var context = drawingCanvas.getContext("2d");
        context.beginPath();
        context.moveTo(0, 0);
        context.lineTo(200, 100);
    });
},0);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use post-link function:

```
link: {
  pre: function preLink(scope, iElement, iAttrs, controller) { ... },
  post: function postLink(scope, iElement, iAttrs, controller) { ... }
}
```

By the time post-link function executes, the html would be rendered.

Comment: Do you mean I shall use:
scope.items = /* some data */

in pre-link and

and $.each in post-link? I've tried as I wrote above but it does not work